# Allocate using #define

Tags: objective-c

I created a preprocessor definition to allocate and construct classes for me as follows:

`#define new(cls) cls* _new() {return [[cls alloc] init];}()`

Now I tried using it like:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) stack
{
    if (!_stack)
    {
        /*_stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];*/
        _stack = new(NSMutableArray);
    }
    return _stack;
}
```

but it says expected expression and unexpected `NSMutableArray` interface. What is wrong with my definition and why can't I do it? Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this I don't even know where to start. Simplest solution though: just don't.

Comment: I solved it. I figured out that the `#define` was declaring a function and calling it inside another function is a no-no. I ended up doing `#define new(cls) [[cls alloc] init]` and it works now. What you do mean "so many things wrong with this". There isn't anything wrong with lazy initialisation. I just don't like objective-c's allocation syntax.

Comment: What's wrong with `[NSMutableArray array];`?

Comment: Or `[NSMutableArray new]` for that matter. This macro just makes the code more confusing and inconsistent. `+new` calls `+alloc` and `-init` and works for all `NSObjects`.

Comment: I was not aware I could do what you just suggested or that new already existed. I'm sitting in my first obj-c class atm and the teacher just makes us copy paste code instead of teaching. I come from C++ and thought that I'd make it easier and define my own new and destructors.

Comment: If you are a new ObjC student, you should absolutely not create macros. You need to first learn ObjC and learn how it does things. Do not try to turn ObjC into C++. You will only confuse yourself. ObjC does many things very differently.

Comment: A few other thoughts you may find useful when coming from other backgrounds: http://robnapier.net/learning-cocoa-2/

Comment: Thank you guys. Just finished the lecture and learned barely anything. I'll be looking through tutorials and stay away from emulating C++ in Obj-C. Also, thank you VERY much for that link! I was using dot operator wrong. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `new`:

```
_stack = [NSMutableArray new];
```

which does the same thing as

```
_stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

No need for a macro which will be confusing to others.

For a long time the use of `new` was discouraged by Apple but it seems with the arrival of ARC it has come back into favor even in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Oops, I did not see Rob's comment.